# (p5.js) RIGHT doesn't trigger in function mouseClicked()?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

For some reason I can't enter the condition `if (mouseButton === RIGHT)`.

```
function mouseClicked()
{
    if (mouseButton === LEFT)
    {
        console.log("left pressed");
        Nodes.push(new Node(mouseX, mouseY));
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("right pressed");
        Attractors.push(new Attractor(mouseX, mouseY));    
    }
}
```

I tried `console.log`ing for both left and right and swapping the orders of the conditions but only `if (mouseButton === LEFT)` gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `mouseClicked` function is only guaranteed to be run when the left mouse button is clicked. You shoud use the [mousePressed](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) or [mouseReleased](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseReleased) instead (according to the [docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseClicked:%7E:text=Browsers%20handle%20clicks%20differently%2C%20so%20this%20function%20is%20only%20guaranteed%20to%20be%20run%20when%20the%20left%20mouse%20button%20is%20clicked.%20To%20handle%20other%20mouse%20buttons%20being%20pressed%20or%20released%2C%20see%20mousePressed()%20or%20mouseReleased().))

Comment: I was almost gonna switch to an alternative, thank you so much!